# Search multiple folder to check if they are empty using powershell

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, scripting

I have a bunch of directories

C:\RI1

C:\RI2

C:\RI3

... C:\RI21

How can I check if they are all empty? I want to go further into the script only if one or more of them have files. If not, I want to exit. I tried this but it is searching for folder names and is giving me 21 as the answer

```
$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem C:\RI* | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo.count

if ($directoryInfo.count -eq 0)
{

    Write-host "Empty"
}

else
{
    Write-host "Not Empty"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run `Get-ChildItem C:\RI*` you get all the child items in C:\ and filter the results with items which begin with "RI". You get the answer 21 since there are 21 folders in C:\ that starts with "RI".

I suggest that you run through all the folders using a `foreach` loop.

```
$folders = @("RI1", "RI2", "RI3")

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
    $path = "C:\$folder"
    $directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $path
    if ($directoryInfo.count -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host "Empty"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Not Empty"
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is, they might add more folders and the folders being added is not in our hands. All we know is, that it would start with RI. Is there a way to do the loop using a wildcard without explicitly specifying the folder name?

Comment: Then you also have to get all the folders in C:\ where the name matches your requirements.
`$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\ | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | where {$_.name.StartsWith("RI")}`

Comment: Wow - If that is the only way it has to happen, I guess I am doomed. Takes a lot of time for the script to execute. 

Thanks a lot for the help David!